How to depend on a set of 4 runtime files, but either all of version 6, or all of version 8?
I'm trying to create an installation package for my application, and it need .NET runtimes. It either needs a set of 4 .NET 6 runtimes, or a set of .NET 8 runtimes, or both. I had it depending on the .NET 6 runtimes, and found it won't install if ONLY the 4 .NET 8 runtimes are installed. Target environment is Ubuntu 22.04.
So I'm trying to figure out how to have something like
Depends: (a6, b6, c6, d6) | (a8, b8, c8, d8)
where a, b, c and d are the runtime package names, and the 6 or 8 is the version. Basically, I don't want (a6, b6, c8, d8). All of one, or all of the other.
Is there some special syntax I need? Or is there different incantation? Thanks.
